# How are "Foil" Badges different from common game Badges?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

As I understand it, crafting a set of regular Steam Trading Cards gets you a common Game Badge. I also know that it is impossible to use a mix of regular and foil cards to craft a badge. Either you craft them entirely with Foil Cards, or you use **no** foil cards. (With the former granting you a Foil Badge instead).

Are Foil Badges **instead** of or **in addition to** regular badges? If the former, can you mix and match Foil / Regular levels? What happens?

Comment: Good question.  Additionally:  Crafting a badge gives you items, such as backgrounds/emoticons.  **Does crafting a foil badge have higher chance of obtaining rare items?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Foil badges are separate from regular badges, and only have one level. Crafting a foil badge will provide 100 Steam XP, the same as a level of the regular badge.

Source: [Steam Trading Card Faq](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq) "There is no extra benefit to having foil cards or foil badges aside from their rarity."

Comment: Is there any interaction between a Foil and a Non-Foil badge? For instance, can you display both badges for a game at once?

Comment: They're completely independent badges, so they'll behave exactly the same way as two badges from different games. The only thing that really ties in foil cards to the regular ones of the same game, is the way they drop in booster packs.

Comment: Given that normal badges have multiple levels, is a foil badge the top-level version of the normal badge (with foil stuff)?

Comment: Nope. A completely separate badge with only one level. Same crafting rewards, just a different look, and harder to get the cards.

Comment: @BillyMailman `the way they drop in booster packs` - do you mean that booster packs give a greater chance of getting a foil than normal crafting?

Comment: @AcidShout I mean that booster packs specifically drop the foil cards for the same game they're from, which is the only mechanic that in any way relates the foil cards of a game to the regular cards of that same game.

Comment: @BillyMailman so you mean that booster packs give foils and not normal cards?

Comment: @AcidShout No, they give either, and mostly normal. But they always give cards related to that game. Which is the only thing that ties a given game's foil cards to its regular cards.